# Pass Fields Via URL to a View?

Tags: views

Use case #1: Display the Demonstration Title and Demonstration ID on the Deliverables view.

Use Case #2: The Deliverables view displays all Deliverables associated with a state specific State Demonstration.

So it seems like I need to pass two fields via URL to the Deliverables view page?

**Content Type:** Demonstration
**Fields:** field_demonstration_title, field_demonstration_id

**Content Type:** Deliverables

[Screen Capture of Workflow](http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/05_w22/915701/viewsflow2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

contextual filters takes arguments from entities whether in the url or not

you could build the url and match arguments with url parts

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please explain, and provide as much detail as you can. I'm just kind of learning how to work with contextual filter and entity reference fields.

Comment: add contextual filter for the field names that you need the view to get results have that fields value

in your case add a C F named demonstration_id to Deliverables view so it will limit results to Deliverables references that value given in the url for example Deliverables/:demonstration_id

Comment: Ok.How should I approach the Context Filter settings in the Deliverables view?

Comment: from advanced settings